# How to remove additional text while raising an error in python

Tags: python, exception

So i made some random stuff:

```
def println(text: str) -> str:
    print(text)
    if not type(text) == str:
        raise TypeError("Text not string type")

println("Hello, World!")
```

Now, when i put a string inside the `println()` function it works perfectly fine. But if i put an integer inside the `println()` function it raises a TypeError with the location where it's coming from like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\???\Desktop\leahnn files\python projects (do not delete)\Main files\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    println(1)
  File "c:\Users\???\Desktop\leahnn files\python projects (do not delete)\Main files\main.py", line 4, in println
    raise TypeError("Text not string type")
TypeError: Text not string type
```

It does raise the TypeError but it's saying where it's coming from. I was wondering if you can just remove the location it's coming from and just say:

```
TypeError: Text not string type
```

If i just do:

```
def println(text: str) -> str:
    print(text)
    if not type(text) == str:
        print("TypeError: Text not string type")
```

It's gonna print out the integer that is inside the `println()` function and it's gonna print the TypeError after the integer inside the `println()` function is done executing. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But why would you want to obscure the source of the error? That's just going to make debugging more difficult.

Comment: @Chris to make it look more neat.

Comment: Why does that matter? Who do you expect to be reading this error message?

Comment: @Chris Myself. I was doing this for fun.

Comment: I suggest you get used to errors not looking "neat". Squashing context information, or error messages entirely, is possible. But you'll quickly find that this makes errors much more frustrating to deal with. They become extremely difficult to understand and troubleshoot.

Comment: @Chris Alright. I know what you mean. Thank you

Comment: This is up to the calling code, not your code. The extra information doesn't come from anything in your code, but from Python internals. It happens because *the calling code* does *not suppress* it by handling the error with `except`.

Comment: What's wrong with your final example? Do you want to print the error without the integer? Then do the test _before_ the print. Do you want `println` to print the message, or the thing calling `println`?

Comment: @chris - It's context dependent. A UI may want to print the error without the traceback which is irrelevant to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle exception with
`try-except` clause
and in `except` just print error message.
See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

```
try:
    println(1)
except TypeError as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: thank you. i can't correct this answer yet because it says i can correct an answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: @Rydex did you mean _accept_?

Comment: Can you write this as an example script?